# Xcode Add (Math) Label and Textfield

Tags: xcode, math, addition

Hi I am trying to add (math not put letters together) a textfield's data, and a label's data together. I have preformed the same code you see below for multiplication but when I do the same (A little changed) it does not seem to work. The code I placed below just shows the value of the billAmountTextField. Do you know why? Thanks for your help!

```
-(IBAction)totalAllUp:(id)sender
{
    NSString *billTotalAmountString = [billAmountTextField text];

    float billTotalFloat =[billTotalAmountString floatValue];

    NSString *tipTotalAmountString = [resultLabel text];

    float tipTotalAmountFloat = [tipTotalAmountString floatValue];

    float totalAmountAfterAdding = billTotalFloat + tipTotalAmountFloat;

    NSString *finalAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", totalAmountAfterAdding];

    [totalAfterAdd setText:finalAnswer];

}
```

Comment: Man your question is not understandable.

Comment: You need to elaborate more what it is that does not work, such as the result you get and the expected result. You also need to check your resultLabel whether it is really connected to the outlet.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. I need to add a textfields data (23) + a labels data (20) and place it in another label. The code above is suposed to add the data together so my final label shows (43). But instead the final label just shows the textfields data (23). I need to figure out where I am messing up, because it should add them together. Thanks.